# Speed up sbt in China when using Chisel

Tags: sbt, chisel

All

I a new users of Chisel in China and I found Chisel is build its program by using sbt.
However, sbt seem need to download a lot of thing before it get to work.
Do anyone have any idea to speed up this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution and download of dependencies can be speeded up by using a proxy repository in China:

1. Create a ~/.sbt/repositories file like [this](https://github.com/thirstycrow/sbt-global-settings/blob/master/repositories).
2. Set SBT_OPTS: `export SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true"`

Check the sbt documentation for more about the [proxy repositories](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html)